# Oauth2 returned image url breaks imagecreatefrompng

Tags: php, imagecreatefrompng

I am using `hybridauth-3.7.1` from oauth library. https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/releases

The library works perfectly so I have the following:

```
<?php
  require_once 'hybridauth-3.7.1/vendor/autoload.php';
  $config = [
    'callback' => 'my_callback_url',
    'keys'     => [
      'id' => 'my_app_id',
      'secret' => 'my_secret'
    ],
  ];
  $adapter = new Hybridauth\Provider\Reddit( $config );
  $adapter->authenticate();
  $userProfile = $adapter->getUserProfile();
  $photo = $userProfile->photoURL;
```

If I echo the $photo I get:
https://styles.redditmedia.com/t5_55fo22/styles/profileIcon_bblqmk8klas71.png?width=256&height=256&crop=256:256,smart&s=30a3bb6af945eadeaddb40271d2c0161ca82768d

now if I try to:

```
imagecreatefrompng($photo);
```

my logs return:

```
imagecreatefrompng( https://styles.redditmedia.com/t5_55fo22/styles/profileIcon_bblqmk8klas71.png?width=256&amp;amp;height=256&amp;amp;crop=256:256,smart&amp;amp;s=30a3bb6af945eadeaddb40271d2c0161ca82768d ): failed`
```

So the url is properly returned in the echo, but as can be seen from the logs imagecreatefrompng is adding a weird &amp;amp;

i have also tried

```
imagecreatefrompng(urldecode($photo));
```

and

```
$decoded_photo = urldecode($photo);
imagecreatefrompng($decoded_photo);
```

both return the same above error logs.

However if I manually type the url in it works fine.

```
imagecreatefrompng( 'https://styles.redditmedia.com/t5_55fo22/styles/profileIcon_bblqmk8klas71.png?width=256&height=256&crop=256:256,smart&s=30a3bb6af945eadeaddb40271d2c0161ca82768d' );
```

How can I get the returned image url to work with imagecreatefrompng?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when directly pasting the url as shown in the last example I was not realizing the cut and paste was different than the actual source.

This means although i was copying `&height=256...` what was in the actual source was `&amp;=256...` Therefore when trying to `imagecreatefrompng()` it was encoding already encoded `&amp;` thus resulting in `&amp;amp;`

The fix was to change the `$userProfile->photoUrl` as displayed below.

```
$photo = htmlspecialchars_decode($userProfile->photoURL);
imagecreatefrompng($photo);
```